# WCF Operation contract type in case of Push Notification message receiving?

Tags: c#, wcf, push-notification

I have Restful WCF service which will be used to read the data push by another Restful service hosted somewhere on the internet. I have to expose one method to read the Json data push by the other service.

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface ITestService
{
    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke( Method = "GET",
        ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json )]
    string GetData(string JsonData);
}
```

Is it fine to receive the Push message in GET method ? Also Push service can send bulk of data at once. how can i restrict it so my server works fine even with bulk data.

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have Restful WCF service which will be used to read the data push by
>   another Restful service hosted somewhere on the internet.

"Push" is probably the wrong word; it's evocative of server-push, which has a different meaning than the way you are using it here. More accurately, you have a service which another service will call, passing some data.

> Is it fine to receive the Push message in GET method ?

No, it's not fine. GET operations pass data on the query string only. This would actually be fine (though quite unusual) for very short strings made up of JSON, but longer strings would risk violating the maximum size limit for query string in whatever technology stack you happen to be using.

Using a POST operation would work:

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface ITestService
{
    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke( Method = "POST",
        RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
        ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
        UriTemplate = "GetData" )]
    string GetData(string JsonData);
}
```

However, you would still need to actually process the JSON string manually. The most usual way of doing this would be to define a c# type which will support serialisation of the JSON:

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface ITestService
{
    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "POST", 
        RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
        ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
        UriTemplate = "GetData" )]
    string GetData(MyData data);
}
```

Where MyData is a c# type which corresponds to your JSON payload. The JSON will be cleanly deserialized to an instance of MyData which will be made available in your method.

Comment: Thanks Tom. My WCF service could get the bulk data at once. Is there a way to restrict it so my server don't get DOS issue.

Comment: @EhsanHafeez there is nothing you can do about ddos attacks on your service beyond what you would normally do: http://linuxgazette.net/126/cherian.html